# I've been trying to use a class to create images of obstacles and nothing happens when I run it

Tags: winforms

I'm trying to create a simple game and I wanted to use classes to have multiple obstacles to spawn and move from right to left. For now I was only focused on actually creating the obstcales anywhere on the screen but nothing seems to be working.

```
public class Obstacles
        {
            public Point postion;
            public Size size;
            public System.Drawing.Bitmap image;

            public PictureBox createObstacle()
            {
                PictureBox rock = new PictureBox();
                rock.Location = postion;
                rock.Size = size;
                rock.Image = image;
                rock.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                return rock;
            }
        }
```

```
            Obstacles obstacles = new Obstacles();

            obstacles.postion = new Point(500, 200);
            obstacles.size = new Size(50, 50);
            obstacles.image = Properties.Resources.pixil_frame_0;

            obstacles.createObstacle();
```

Can someone let me know if theres something wrong with my method or how I call the class? I've created a blank picturebox in the form and named it rock still to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Rati,

Assuming you are using WinForms for your project.
You will need to return the `PictureBox` object you create in the `createObstacle` method and add it to the `Controls` collection in the form.

For example,

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Obstacles obstacles = new Obstacles();

    obstacles.postion = new Point(500, 200);
    obstacles.size = new Size(50, 50);
    obstacles.image = Properties.Resources.pixil_frame_0;

    var obstacle = obstacles.createObstacle();
    
    Controls.Add(obstacle);
}
```